# Append em javascript não permite interação/refresh posterior

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo uma rolagem infinita em uma página, com javascript.

Ele funciona bem, traz os resultados. Até aí, tudo ok.

Mas, tenho uma div que tem "likes" que dá refresh automático quando há interação (atualiza a contagem). Quando carregam os próximos registros, ao final do scroll, ele permite a interação com os "likes", mas quando dá o refresh na div dos "likes", a div fica oculta (grava os dados, mas a div não mostra nada).

Seguem os códigos:

**Rolagem Infinta**

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#agrupa-lt").scroll(function() { 
      if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() > $(this).get(0).scrollHeight - 2) {
        //requisição ajax para selecionar postagens
        $.ajax({
           url:'arquivo-carrega-mais.php', //Página PHP que seleciona postagens
           type:'POST', // método post, GET ...
           data: 'contagem='.concat(contagem), //seus paramêtros
           success: function(data){ // sucesso de retorno executar função
             $('#agrupa-lt').append(data); // adiciona o resultado na div #conteudo
           } // fim success
        }); // fim ajax
      } // fim do if
    }); // fim scroll
})); // fim document ready
```

**Botões Curtir**

```
function like<?php echo $variavel['id']; ?>()
    {
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: '/grava-likes.php',
                data: {postid: '<?php echo $variavel['id']; ?>', tipo: 'tipo-like', userid: '<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>', idautor: <?php echo $autor['id']; ?>},
                success: function()
                       {
                           $("#like<?php echo $variavel['id']; ?>").load(document.URL +  " #like<?php echo $variavel['id']; ?>>*", "");
                       }

            });
    }
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Parece que a função 'like' não está atualizando a DOM para exibir o div, ou você faz isso em outro momento?

Comment: @MarcosAlexandre, realmente não está atualizando a DOM, mas é por que não consegui fazer a atualização da div assim. Consegue me dar uma ajuda sobre isso?